# How to execute .exe tool with argument using Powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I want to execute a tool with some argument. I use powershell script to execute it. When I execute the powershell script, it works. But when I use other powershell script to call the first script, it can not work only the part of executing the tool.

This is the first script to execute the tool. it works, if execute only this script.

```
$Path = "C:\Tool"
$IP = 10.1.1.1
Write-Host $IP
$Find = "ABC123"
Write-Host $Find
$Folder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "C:\DW"
& $Path\Assembly.exe --sserver $IP --assembly $Find --localpath $Folder
Start-Sleep -s 1
```

This is the second script, I do some process, then call the first script. And it does not work in this part

```
& $Path\Assembly.exe --sserver $IP --assembly $Find --localpath $Folder
```

Second Script

```
#### Do some process ####
$Button1                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.BackColor               = "#136aa4"
$Button1.text                    = "OK"
$Button1.width                   = 70
$Button1.height                  = 27
$Button1.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(960,57)
$Button1.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$Button1.AutoSize                = $true
$Button1.ForeColor               = "#ffffff"

$Button1.Add_Click({  

    $result = & ".\Get.ps1" $TextBox1.Text
    Write-Host $result
#---------------------- Download ML -----------------------#
    & ".\DW.ps1" ##### THIS IS MY FIRST SCRIPT TO EXECUTE THE TOOL #####
#----------------------------------------------------------#
    if($result.Length -gt 0){  
        $Global:status = "active" 
        $Button2.Visible = $true
        $Button3.Visible = $true

        $filePath_file = Get-ChildItem "C:\DW\Order0\*.txt"
        $filePath = Get-Content $filePath_file


###### DO Some process #######
```

Comment: Are you facing issue in calling & ".\DW.ps1" ?

Comment: I don't think so. because I can execute this  & ".\DW.ps1"  but this part can not execute `& $Path\Assembly.exe --sserver $IP --assembly $Find --localpath $Folder`

Comment: Try `Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList C:\DW\DW.ps1` instead of `& ".\DW.ps1"`

Comment: or you can try & powershell.exe ".\DW.ps1"

Comment: It's not work @Sid

Comment: it doesnt work @NirajGajjar

Comment: Have you tried Start-Job { & powershell.exe ".\DW.PS1" } ?

Comment: yes, It does not work @NirajGajjar

Comment: "It does not work" is not a valid problem description. How *exactly* does it "not work"? What behavior do you expect? What behavior do you actually see? Are you getting errors? If so, what do they say? Is the script being invoked at all? Your code is trying to invoke `DW.ps1` from the current working directory. Is that directory what you expect it to be? How did you verify that?

Comment: With those comment, the powershell script ‘DW.ps1’ does not execute. With my script above, it execute the script ‘DW.ps1’ but that part I mentioned does not execute